# Memory Profiling, How to find variable name associated with object

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, guppy

I have a python application that is over time consuming GB's of data..
To track down the memory usage I installed `guppy` and printed the heap after a time unit, I see the following in the report.

```
Partition of a set of 43325494 objects. Total size = 7524458264 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 2556102   6 2678794896  36 2678794896  36 dict of cocotb.binary.BinaryValue
...
```

Now objects of type BinaryValue are created in dozens of modules in my application.
To progress with the debug I will have to get the line number/filename/variable name of these objects. So
Is there some way to obtain this information?
If not, then what strategies can I use to rootcause the issue?

*Note:Since the python application is tightly coupled to a C program it is not possible to run the python code interactively and any debug steps has to be directly instrumented in the code.*

Answer (score 0):

The direct referred 'name' is shown in the `byvia` attribute, like:

```
heap()[0].byvia
```

Considering your set is `dict of [something]` the via will always be `.__dict__`, so doing a `referrers` will be more useful:

```
heap()[0].referrers.byvia
```

The reference pattern is shown in the `rp` attribute and the shortest path from root (guppy's traverse tree) is shown in the `sp` attribute:

```
heap()[0].rp
heap()[0].sp
```

I personally prefer filtering to set of objects of interest, then get one somgle object from the set (eg: `.byid[0]`), and do a shortest path to that.

The documentation of all the different attributes are [python 3 version](https://zhuyifei1999.github.io/guppy3/heapy_UniSet.html) and [python 2 version](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/heapy_UniSet.html)